# a:active issue in ie6

Tags: css, hyperlink, internet-explorer-6

I'm having some questions about changing the class/state of a link back to normal in ie6. I'm using a:active to change the background of a span when the user clicks on it. The target of the link is set to javascript:void(0), so clicking on the link just invokes a JS function I have. 
However, when the user releases the mouse button, the a:active state to be removed for the link, the background changed back to normal, but in ie6 it does not. It keeps the depressed background I've set in a:active.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In IE6, "active" is sometimes analogous to "focused". The DOM object will remain "active" until another element receives focus, or it is blurred. If you add a JavaScript onMouseUp event to the link which calls `blur()`, it should release the active state when the user's mouse button releases:

```
<a href="whatever">Link!</a>
...
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function handleMouseup() {
        window.event.srcElement.blur();
    }

    if(ie6) {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
            links[i].onmouseup = handleMouseup;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This will ensure you can use any href you want (javascript:void(0), #, whatever)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use href="#" on IE6, I've had the same problem, using javascript:void(0) in most of the links and working fine on IE7 and FF, so running a js specifically on IE6 browsers replacing javascript:void(0) for # and it works now.

Comment: If you do this (use href="#") and perform some action in an onClick handler, make sure you stop the default behavior of the link (by returning false from the inline handler or calling event.preventDefault) or else you will get directed to the top of the page when you click on the link.

Comment: "#" jumps the browser to the default anchor, which is the top of the page. If the user is scrolled down at all, this is very disruptive.